# Connecting two TFT LCD screens to Raspberry Pi

Tags: screen

I need to connect two small [TFT LCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TFT_LCD) screens to Raspberry Pi and two push buttons. Does Raspberry Pi have enough [GPIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Purpose_Input/Output) pins for this? What TFT screens can be recommended to do this?

Comment: Can you get a GPIO expander?